# Remove Double Quotes at Begin & End from JSON Object/String or Java script Variable?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, javascript-framework

I'm getting a JSON Array of objects from servlet and trying to populate in a table control in java script.

Here is my code, for some reason it is putting double quotes at the beginning and End, which is not accepted by Table control for populating values. how can I remove this double quotes at beginning and End.

```
 aData = [{"A":"one","B":"Two","C":"Three","D":"8","E":"No","F":"Business","G":"0",
 "L1H":"Analytics"},{"A":"ones","B":"Twos","C":"Threes","D":"85","E":"Nos",
 "F":"BusinessD","G":"0","L1H":"AnalyticsM"}]

 var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
 oModel.setData({modelData: aData});
 var oTable=sap.ui.getCore().byId("id1");
 oTable.setModel(oModel);
 oTable.bindRows("/modelData"); // This static code of aData is working fine in
                                // my Table   control of HTMl page.

 //Here, i Wanted to get values dynamically from servlet and populate it in Table.
  var global;
  $.get('someServlet', function(data) { 
 var abc, xyz;
for(var i=0;i<(data.length);i++){
 abc='{'+'\"A\":'+'\"'+data[i].A+'\"'+','+'\"B":'+'\"'+data[i].B+'\"'+',
 '+'\"C\":'+'\"'+data[i].C+'\"'+','+'\"D\":'+'\"'+data[i].D+'\"'+',
 '+'\"E\":'+'\"'+data[i].E+'\"'+','+'\"F\":'+'\"'+data[i].F+'\"'+',
 '+'\"G\":'+'\"'+data[i].G+'\"'+','+'\"H\":'+'\"'+data[i].H+'\"}';   
        if (xyz===undefined)
            xyz=abc;
        else                
        xyz=abc+','+xyz;
            global = xyz;
        }
        global="["+global+"]";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({modelData: global});
        var oTable=sap.ui.getCore().byId("id1");
        oTable.setModel(oModel);
        oTable.bindRows("/modelData");

    });
     //global="[{"A":"one","B":"Two","C":"Three"}...]"
     //alert(global);  Displaying without double quotes as expected.
     //when I see the value in Chrome debugger double quotes are appearing at begin&End
```

So Finally I have value in global variable is, with double quotes.

```
//global="[{"A":"one","B":"Two","C":"Three","D":"8","E":"No","F":"Business","G":"0","L1H":"Analytics"},
```

{"A":"ones","B":"Twos","C":"Threes","D":"85","E":"Nos","F":"BusinessD","G":"0","L1H":"AnalyticsM"}]"

how can I get rid of this double quotes at beginning and end of this resultSet JSONArray Objects? If I put Alert, it is displaying without double Quotes. when I see this global variable in Chrome debugger, it is showing with Double quotes and failing to populate values in Table control. I'm having bit hard time with my code in populating values into Table control which are coming from Servlet in JSON format/String/Array. Please help.

Appreciate of any input and help.

Comment: So it looks like your ajax returns json, but you're trying to strip out all but three properties, so you're doing manual json string building, and trying to pass that to a function? Is that right?

Comment: wow. i didn't realize that's what he was doing. that's silly.

Comment: You can use [stringify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498413/remove-double-quotes-at-begin-end-from-json-object-string-or-java-script-varia) to convert the json to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parse your string into an object at the very end, that is:

```
global=JSON.parse("["+global+"]");
```

But instead of building yourself a string of JSON on the fly and then parsing it, it may just be simpler to set `var global = [];` and in your for loop do:

```
global.push({ 
    Deals: data[i].Deals, 
    L1H: data[i].L1H, 
    L2H: data[i].L2H 
});
```

Have you tried the following?

```
$.get('someServlet', function(data) { 
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({modelData: data});
    var oTable=sap.ui.getCore().byId("id1");
    oTable.setModel(oModel);
    oTable.bindRows("/modelData");
});
```

Comment: This is what I have in th doGet method of servlet  response.getWriter().print(jsonArray); when I do alert(data), getting such as [object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object

Comment: Right, because data is an array of objects, which should be sufficient enough to populate the table control (depending on how or what you're using to do that). If you want the textual representation of the data, you can just do `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`, but if none of our answers have helped you yet, then we may be misunderstanding the problem you're having.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry for making you confusion. Let me put in different way.

Comment: I'm getting an error in this type of format such as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

Don't build or parse json yourself. There are methods available to do it for you.

If your returned json only has an array of objects with the three properties `Deals`, `L1H`, and `L2H`, then `data` is what you want. If the returned json has more properties, and you only want those three, do this instead:

```
function(data) {

    var arr = $.map(data, function(item, idx) {
        return {
            Data: item.Data,
            L1H: item.L1H,
            L2H: item.L2H
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all responses. Actually I'm passing Database resultSet in JSON Array format to servlet. this is the JSON Array that I'm passing to servlet.[{"A":"one","B":"Two","C":"Three","D":"8","E":"No","F":"Business","G":"0","L1H":"Analytics"},
{"AB":"one","BC":"Two","CD":"Three","DF":"8","EG":"No","FZ":"Business","GM":"0","L1H":"Analytics"}
] . that means, the number of rows returned from JDBC program.

Comment: If I don't parse by myself in the code, then getting an error.

Comment: I re-iterated my question on other way. would anyone please take a look of my concern again?

Answer (score 1):

Your `global` variable is a JSON string.  You don't need to construct a string.  As far as I can tell, `data` is already a JavaScript object.  I think this is what you want:

```
var global;    
$.get('someServlet', function(data) {
    global = data;
    populateTable(global);  // You could just as easily pass the data variable here
});
```

Comment: I'm able to populate table with static data such as global=[{"A":"one","B":"Two","C":"Three","D":"8","E":"No","F":"Business","G":"0","L1H":"Analytics"},
{"AB":"one","BC":"Two","CD":"Three","DF":"8","EG":"No","FZ":"Business","GM":"0","L1H":"Analytics"}
] when I get values in this global variable from data, it is failling. how can I achieve this?

Comment: In my example above, you should just be able to call the function to populate that table immediately after you set the global variable.  I edited my example to show what I mean.

Comment: this is failing. when I assign global directly to Table control, getting an error. when I do like this global = [{"A":"one","B":"Two","C":"Three","D":"8","E":"No","F":"Business","G":"0","L1H":"Analytics"},{"AB":"one","BC":"Two","CD":"Three","DF":"8","EG":"No","FZ":"Business","GM":"0","L1H":"Analytics"}]; Populate(global), it is working

Comment: Please put `console.log(data);` inside the $.get callback function.  What does it display in the console?

Comment: [object,Object],[object,Object],[object,Object],[object,Object],[object,Object],[object,Object]....

Answer (score 0):

Since you are usig jQuery, try http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ and it will return you an object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var myJSON = eval( data );
```

where data is the string that the servelt has sent. Eval function makes the work, parse a string into JSON.

Answer (score -1):

La forma correcta de eliminar las comillas es con

```
var obJason = eval( dataString );

var obj= "[{"ID":"786-000X-XX8","NAME":"LISANDRO ARCILES"}]";
```

aplicado la funcion `eval()`

```
obj= eval( obj);
```

lo tranforma al obejeto deseado de tipo Json

Comment: Please post in English only